# error pushing to my git hub repository from git

Tags: git, github

```
C:\Users\sdand\Documents\agronet>git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to sdandersonz97/agronet.git denied to sdandersonz.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sdandersonz97/agronet.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

i try pushed but in my first attempt i typed wrong the user, in the pop up form i typed sdandersonz and is sdandersonz97 and now i cant push my repository i change mi git email but nothing works !.

im using windows 10
i appreciate your help

Comment: Can you try to change your username and email like this https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Comment: that not works @IshankGulati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If problem is coming on windows then remove the Credentials from the Windows history.

- Go to Credential Manager
- Go to Windows Credentials
- Delete the entries under Generic Credentials
- Try connecting again.This time , it should prompt you for the correct username and password.

[image]
[image]